# Why is the server ignoring rewrite on non ASPX files?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

Locally this works but on the server when i do something like /user/profile i get a 404 however if i do /user/profile.aspx it works. I also rewrite images from /s/example.png to /localLocation/example.png, this doesnt work. If i write /localLocation/example.png it does show up however it defeats the purpose of my rewriting. Also if i attach a .aspx to the end of any path i get a default page which shows the address of the rewrite. It is correct but only if i add .aspx. How do i get the server to apply the rewrite to all paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that IIS only invokes ASP .Net for certain extensions.

You need to configure IIS to use ASP .Net to handle every extension that you want to rewrite.

**EDIT**

If your web host runs IIS 7 in Integrated Mode (ask them), you need to add the `HttpModule` that handles the rewriting to the `modules` tag in `system.webserver`.  See [here](http://ruslany.net/2008/09/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/)

Comment: Its a free host so i have no idea.
Now i have somewhere to start, looking for an extension config

Comment: Which host is it?  Which version of Windows do they run? (They should say)

Comment: @SLaks IIRC Windows Server 2008, using framework version 2.0.50727.0 (i dont know what that means, it was wonder ASP.NET config and .NET 3.5 seems to be supported)

Comment: Then it runs IIS 7.  Find out whether they run in integrated mode; if they do, it'll be much easier.